# Following a WCF binding configuration naming convention

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

Is there a well-established naming convention in use for WCF binding configurations that someone could recommend? When examining the WCF/ WF samples from Microsoft, for example, there are multiple conventions used, including:

- Binding + sequence number (e.g. "Binding1") is used most of the time
- ProtocolName + Binding (e.g. "TcpBinding") is used for custom bindings
- QueueName + Binding (e.g. OrderProcessorBinding) is used for msmq bindings
- Binding description (e.g. "BindingWithSession") is used in some cases

Binding configuration names in projects I've worked on are similarly idiosyncratic. Should one desire greater consistency, is there an established convention one could follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binding is a "recipe" for how the WCF channel stack will be assembled.

In theory, every time you configure a binding configuration section in your wcf config (or in code) you are specifying some fairly exact behaviour that you require from the binding.

So your binding name should really describe the "recipe" which you are using.

As examples, if you are modifying send time-outs to support long running operations this should be reflected in your binding name. Similarly, if you are setting the binding security to transport-only for interoperability, then this could also be reflected.

Bindings allow you to specify a wide range of behaviour, for example you may have a binding which is used with activex clients for which you may need to select an alternative formatter for serialisation. Naming this binding "Binding1" doesn't really explain what it's doing.

So I think the binding should describe the recipe.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. Developers should be able to look at the composition of an endpoint and know what its intent is. If it's intended to support a special need, reflecting that in the name of the binding configuration should help make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it really doesn't matter. Pick a convention that works well for you and be consistent with it throughout your own code. As you've already pointed out - there is a lot of inconsistency across the various projects you've observed. You might borrow ideas from other code you've read - but I think the important part is to just be consistent in your own code.

Comment: That's absolutely reasonable. My present client tends to favor conventions that come from an established authority (Microsoft, Fowler, Erl, etc...), though. In the absence of that, though, we'll need to go with common sense.